# Ansible Filter regex_search does not Exist

Tags: regex, ansible

I have this snipped of code from our playbook:

```
- name: Set version
  set_fact:
    my_version: "My version is {{ my_file.stdout | regex_search('[0-9\.]+') }}"
```

... where my_file is 'program_1.2.3_install.exe'

It returns that the filter regex_search does not exist.
We are running Ansible 2.0.0.2

Does anybody know how to make this regex work?
Thanks!

Comment: It is nothing to do with the actual regex pattern, but that the Ansible filter 'regex_search' does not exist... And, this is just an example of our actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given the variable

```
my_file: 'program_1.2.3_install.exe'
```

The task

```
   - set_fact:
        my_version: "{{ my_file|regex_replace(myregex, myreplace) }}"
      vars:
        myregex: '^(.*?)([0-9\.]+)(.*)$'
        myreplace: '\2'
    - debug:
        var: my_version
```

gives

```
    "my_version": "1.2.3"
```

It's also possible to use `split()`. The task below gives the same result

```
    - set_fact:
        my_version: "{{ my_file.split('_').1 }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_version
```